Unix error "Invalid RangeEnd" using sed on OracleLinux8.9 - code works onOL 7.9
I amfacing an error working with sed on files.
We have this core running successfully on OracleLinux 7.9 but onOracleLinux 8.9 the same code fails with invalid range end
sed -r -f ./sed/transform-diff.sed  < 15-diffToUpdate.xml > 15-diffToUpdate.xml.tmp
sed: file ./sed/transform-diff.sed line 11: Invalid range end
where transform-diff-sed is:
# sed script to transform generated Liquibase diff file

# Problem to solve: If a column is dropped, a RDBM drops as well every index, that uses these columns. In the
# Liquibase diff script, columns are dropped first, indexes later. In the previously described case, an index
# might already be deleted and the update might fail.
# Solution: Put every <dropIndex> in a separate <changeSet>, containing a <indexExists> preCondition that
# only executes the <dropIndex> if it still exists.
/<changeSet/ {
    N
    s%([ \t]*)<changeSet author="([a-zA-Z \(\)]*)" id="([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)">[ \t\n]*(<dropIndex indexName="([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)"[a-zA-Z_-=" ]*>)%\1<changeSet author="\2" id="\3a">\n\1\1<preConditions onFail="CONTINUE">\n\1\1\1<indexExists indexName="\5" />\n\1\1</preConditions>\n\1\1\4\n\1</changeSet>\n\1<changeSet author="\2" id="\3b">%g
}

# Problem to solve: Liquibase diff reads from type FLOAT not the precision but the the required bytes adds
# this information to its change log. A FLOAT (with default precision of 126) is transformed to a FLOAT(22),
# which is too short. By removing all precision information in the generated diff file, we avoid this
# problem.
/type="FLOAT\(/ {
    s%type="FLOAT\([0-9]*\)"%type="FLOAT"%g
}


Any hints how to proceed ? The sed commands were developed years ago and could been changed. I do need to get it running
I isolated the code and get it running on two seperate machines
1.) Oracle Linux 7.9 --> works fine, Output-File is filled
2.) Oracle Linux 8.9 --> error message, Output-File is empty
tia
Uwe

what is the output of sed --version or what is the version of sed on both systems?

@KamilCuk
on 8.9 it is :
[oracle@rcsdickendb calculated]$ cat /etc/oracle-release
Oracle Linux Server release 8.9
[oracle@rcsdickendb calculated]$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.5
on 7.9:
[oracle@rcsechodb calculated]$ cat /etc/oracle-release
Oracle Linux Server release 7.9
You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/oracle
[oracle@rcsechodb calculated]$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

seemslike our internal AI helped to solve the error - so this must been a difference between the Versions ofsed in 7.9 and 8.9
Functioning code is:
s%([ \t]*)<changeSet author="([a-zA-Z \(\)]*)" id="([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)">\s*(<dropIndex indexName="([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)"[^>]*>)%\1<changeSet author="\2" id="\3a">\n\1\1<preConditions onFail="CONTINUE">\n\1\1\1<indexExists indexName="\5" />\n\1\1</preConditions>\n\1\1\4\n\1</changeSet>\n\1<changeSet author="\2" id="\3b">%g

